# Erro com função sem_init() no Linux

Tags: c, linux

Estou tentando resolver um problema com `semáforos`, mas quando tento utilizar a função `sem_init()` obtenho um erro dizendo que há referência indefinida,
sabem me dizer por quê?

Eu tenho a biblioteca de `semáforos` incluída.

**Código (C):**

```
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<sys/sem.h>

int pos_escrita;
int pos_leitura;

int buffer[10]; //capacidade para 10

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
sem_t vazio;
sem_t cheio;

// IDs das threads
int id_produtores[100];
int id_consumidores[10];

void init()
{
    sem_init(&vazio, 0, 10);
    sem_init(&cheio, 0, 0);
    pos_escrita = 0;
    pos_leitura = 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    init();
    pthread_t threads[2]; // nº de threads

    for(i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

O erro apresentado foi:

> /tmp/ccTcI1EU.o: In function init': f.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined
>   reference to sem_init' f.c:(.text+0x3a): *undefined reference to
>   sem_init' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status*

Comment: Tente colocar `-lrt` ou `-lpthread` ao compilar: `gcc codigo.c -lpthread -o codigo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o post no SO (em inglês): [Undefined Reference issues using Semaphores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556042/undefined-reference-issues-using-semaphores)

Se você estiver em um sistema Linux, você precisa incluir a biblioteca `pthreads` e `rt` (conforme a documentação em [Synchronizing Threads with POSIX Semaphores](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html)) durante os processos de compilação e link, pois o erro demonstra que a implementação da função não foi encontrada ao linkar o programa.

Exemplo:

`gcc -o arquivo_saida arquivo_fonte.c -lpthread -lrt`

Observação: no comando acima, os nomes das bibliotecas devem vir após o(s) arquivo(s) `.c`.

Answer (score 1):

O erro que você obteve é um erro de *linkagem*. O seu código C está correto e as funções que você usa estão declaradas nos arquivos ".h" que você inclui. No entanto, na hora de gerar o executável o seu compilador não está encontrando a implementação das funções de semáforos.

A solução é adicionar a flag `-lpthread` na hora de compilar o seu programa.